# Validating user input in Java (strings)

Tags: java, string, validation

I'm trying to figure out how to validate user input for a program that asks for the date, month, and year as a "password", and if they get it wrong, to show an error message. The date, month, and year have to be strings. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {

public static void main (String[]args){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Login");

    String day = "";
    do {
        System.out.println("Today's day?");
        while (!sc.hasNextString()) {
            System.out.println("ERROR Please try again");
            sc.next();
        }

        day = sc.nextString();
    } while (day >= 1 && day <= 31);
        System.out.println("Today's month?");
    }

    String month = "";
    String year = "";
}
```

Eclipse gives me an error message saying "sc cannot be resolved." Not sure what to do about that. Also, would I have to do the same code to validate for the month and year? I'm an extreme newbie to Java so any guidance would be appreciated greatly thanks <3

Comment: Replace `sc` with `console` .

Comment: Even i f you correct the compile error, your program logic is broken. The inner `while`-loop is the problem (aside from the fact that `Scanner` has no methode `hasNextString()`). You need some program logic to validate that the entered `String` represents an `int` with the correct value.

Comment: `day` is a String. You can't compare it with an integer. You can however parse the String to an integer, and compare the result with another integer.

Comment: If `day`, `month` and `year` are meant to be integers then you should use `hasNextInt` and `nextInt` to check and read, with this you can easily compare them with integers without the need to parse them fisrt, like this your `ERROR Please try again` loop will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidateDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String day, month, year;
        boolean validatedDate = false;

        day = scan.nextLine();
        month = scan.nextLine();
        year = scan.nextLine();

        if (validatedInterval(day,1,31) && validatedInterval(month,1,12) && validatedInterval(year,1900,2015)) {
            validatedDate = true;
        }

        if (!validatedDate) {
            System.out.println("This is an incorrect date");
        }

        scan.close();
    }

    public static boolean validatedInterval(String value, int min, int max) {
        boolean validated = false;

        if (Integer.parseInt(value)>=min && Integer.parseInt(value)<=max) {
            validated = true;
        }

        return validated;
    }
}
```

This is the output of the program:

```
33
11
2011
This is an incorrect date
```